# Why are my windows black when trying to shade with HDRI?

Tags: shaders, hdri, archipack-add-on

Using archipack for the windows, and Blender 2.93 for a class I'm in! This is for an assignment, and I thought I followed all of my prof's steps, but apparently I did not. Image is provided, and will provide more info if needed. Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: If you are using EEVEE Render engine, you need to activate "Screen Space Reflection" but you need to give more information about your settings and your materials to be sure

Comment: pls provide blend file ....or search here for same question. Was asked 100x....